# Binding raw XML to datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, datagrid, dataset

I want to bind raw xml file to datagrid and to display that on WPF form using C#. I planed to use dataset to store my xml, and then bind dataset to datagrid. My xml look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<games>
  <game id="123456" name="501">
    <player id="1">
      <name>john</name>
      <score>495</score>
      <movesLeft>15</movesLeft>
      <won>No</won>
      <completed>uncompleted</completed>
    </player>
    <player id="2">
      <name>
         konj
      </name>
      <score>501</score>
      <movesLeft>15</movesLeft>
      <won>No</won>
      <completed>uncompleted</completed>
    </player>
  </game>
</games>
```

i plan to use two datagrids one for  and one for  
with columns id, name, movesLeft, won, completed tied to element

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+bind+xml&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US&ie=utf8&oe=utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best place to start would be with the XmlTextReader class (System.Xml)

Best resource I found for this is straight from MS [XmlTextReader Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548) 
It lets you read the xml file and parse through it by element type/name/etc.

Hope this helps.

From there, you can parse those to DataTables as normal and then bind them to the grid, also as normal. If you need info on that too, let me know

Comment: so you say that i should use DataTables instead of DataSet? On that link is about reading XML and writing it on console. I was wondering is there way to automatically bind XML to datagrid, and define columns by writing XPath query for them.

Comment: Ah, well in that case...here's another link that may help: http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/binding-raw-xml-to-a-datagrid-control-in-asp-net/

Comment: Thanks. Can i use XPath there? And how?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe XPath is only relevant when used to bind to an XMLNode. This topic here may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199721/how-to-bind-xml-to-the-wpf-datagrid-correctly

Comment: I tried instructions from your link. Like this

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Uri DataPath = new Uri("c:\\Data\\xmlfile1.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
ds.ReadXml(DataPath.OriginalString); 
dataGrid1.DataSource = ds; 
dataGrid1.DataBind();

But dataGrid1 do not have property DataSource, or DataBind. Is DataContext instead DataSource ok?

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest taking a look at the StackOverflow link I posted later, using XLinq. What Natxo answered is a much more elegant solution than the other site.

Comment: ok i decided to use xlinq its more suits my purpose. but i have problem with xlinq. why this is not working 
string path = @"D:\xml\dartsDatabase.xml";
            XElement file = XElement.Load(path);
var query = from f in file.Element("games").Elements("game")
                        where (string)f.Attribute("id") == "123"
                        select (string)f.Element("name");