# Binding XML to wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF data grid and an xmlString and am having problems binding it.

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199721/how-to-bind-xml-to-the-wpf-datagrid-correctly) and followed the instructions but cant get it to work.

I see the column with the title but no data is in there. Any ideas?

I should say the code behind is called when a button is clicked after the window has loaded.

Here is my XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[panel]}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="PanelCode" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[panelCode].InnerText}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is my codebehind

```
System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(response);
            XElement results = XElement.Load(reader);
            dtgMain.DataContext = results;
```

here is my xml

```
<data>
  <load count="2">true
    <panel index="10">
      <panelCode>100072
      </panelCode>
      <panelName>COM0100072*A
      </panelName>
      <panelPart>100072
      </panelPart>
      <numberLayers>4
      </numberLayers>
      <panelSize.display>21.0 x 24.0
      </panelSize.display>
      <lastEdited.display>16/11/2011 17:13:39
      </lastEdited.display>
      <panelStatus.display>Measurements Stored
      </panelStatus.display>
      <lastEditor>admin
      </lastEditor>
      <numberBonds>1
      </numberBonds>
      <numberSubComponents>0
      </numberSubComponents>
    </panel>
    <panel index="11">
      <panelCode>100352
      </panelCode>
      <panelName>COM0100352*C
      </panelName>
      <panelPart>100352
      </panelPart>
      <numberLayers>8
      </numberLayers>
      <panelSize.display>18.0 x 24.0
      </panelSize.display>
      <lastEdited.display>16/11/2011 17:18:47
      </lastEdited.display>
      <panelStatus.display>Measurements Stored
      </panelStatus.display>
      <lastEditor>admin
      </lastEditor>
      <numberBonds>1
      </numberBonds>
      <numberSubComponents>0
      </numberSubComponents>
    </panel>
  </load>
</data>
```

Comment: In my opinion you should be using the `XmlDocument` family of XML classes as they support [`Binding.XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx).

Comment: H.B would you please be able to post a code example or at least link to some examples?

Comment: Logically there *is* an example in the `XPath` property documentation i linked to.

Comment: HB there are 2 things that stick out with that example. The first is that its using a static xml file instead of a programatically generated on as in my example. The second thing is that its bingding to a list box instead of a datagrid. Would you be able to give examples of how to use this in my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XElement does not have an 'InnerText' property.

Have you tried using

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Element[panelCode].Value}"
```

instead?

#### Edit:

I just tested with a sample project and the only other change (besides using .Value) is changing your ItemsSource of your DataGrid to include the 'load' node:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Element[load].Elements[panel]}"
```

So your data grid will look like the following:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Element[load].Elements[panel]}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="PanelCode" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[panelCode].Value}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I started off using that and am sure I had the same situation. I will change and show the result :D

Comment: Using value results in the same situation of nothing being displayed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a solution that I have tested (in .NET 4) and verified it works. It appears the initial <data> node is treated as the root, but you cannot just ignore the <load> node and skip straight to <panel> as you were doing.