# Add Data to Xml file on Button Click in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

For example I have the an xml file with BookDetails and I displayed it on the GridView form. Now I want to provide add, edit, delete option to the GridView. I know how to give add, edit, delete options to gridview when we use DataBinding to from SQL datasource but here we should store data to already existing xml file.

Xml file with data:

```
 <books>
    <book>
        <title>CLR via C#</title>
        <isbn>0735667454</isbn>
        <author>Jeffrey Richter</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Pro C# 5.0 and the .NET 4.5 Framework</title>
        <isbn>1430242337</isbn>
        <author>Andrew Troelsen</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Building Windows 8 Apps with C# and XAML</title>
        <isbn>0321822161</isbn>
        <author>Jeremy Likness</author>
    </book>
</books>
```

ASP.NET code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Book Store</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvBooks" runat="server">
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

C# code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bindXml();
    }
    private void bindXml()
    {
        //Create a DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //Load the XML data into the DataSet
        ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("books.xml"));

        //Bind the DataSet to the GridView control
        gvBooks.DataSource = ds;
        gvBooks.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean save to an xml file on button click or write every change to an xml file that is kept open?

Comment: Why can you not simply bind to the XML just as you would to a SQL table or any other such data source:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199721/how-to-bind-xml-to-the-wpf-datagrid-correctly