# Reading a XML and import it into a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xml, datagrid

I have a XML file which looks like:

```
<code>
    <rccontroller>
        <experiment>
            <profile name="Profile 1" scanCycle="1" profileTime="32.76" attenuator="31" archive="" coded="true">
                 <mode name="Mode 1" scanCycle="1" method="DBS" prf="1000" baudWidth="1" baudNo="16" positions="Z" coded="true">
                     <beam name="Beam 1" scanAngle="0" azimuth="0" offset="0" rmin="1" rmax="20" nci="256" nfft="256" nsa="1" nrgb="128" uiName="Z"/>
                 </mode>
            </profile>
        </experiment>
    </rccontroller> 
</code>
```

I need to import the mode and beam into a `DataGrid`, where mode will be the parent grid and Beam will be the Children of the Parent grid.

I have problem reading the inner tags of a element in XML.

So kindly direct me the way of how to read a XML inner elements and put it in a `GridView` as well as how to add a children `GridView` for a grid and do the same for it.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try something? in WPF datagrid you can use XPath to bind to XML elements. For child grid you may need to specify you datagridrow template and do XPath bindings for inner items there

Comment: see some references http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199721/how-to-bind-xml-to-the-wpf-datagrid-correctly http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mamta_m/binding-xml-to-a-wpf-datagrid/

Comment: Hey Bjoshi, lets just forget about child Grid View and all.
I just want to retrieve the values of inner elements of Mode and Beam...

Comment: I will put that comment as an answer to have code formatting, then we can work from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a data.xml file from your xml

in XAML I added a XMLDataProvider which reads that file and then we can use it ahead

```
<XmlDataProvider Source="data.xml" x:Key="dataSource" XPath="code/rccontroller/experiment/profile"/>
```

here we say that we are interested in all the profiles

then in datagrid we use the modes and display mode and beam name

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgXml" DataContext="{StaticResource dataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=mode}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mode name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@name}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beam name" Binding="{Binding XPath=beam/@name}"/>                
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

As you can see we bound the datagrid DataContext to dataSource which is our XMLDataProvider and its ItemsSource to Xpath of Mode in that datacontext and then in the column1 is the name of the mode while in column 2 its beam name

**EDITED**

XAML (only the grid part)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider Source="data.xml" x:Key="dataSource" XPath="code/rccontroller/experiment/profile"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgXml" DataContext="{StaticResource dataSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=mode}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mode name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Beam name" Binding="{Binding XPath=beam/@name}"/>                
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

put your xml in file, name it data.xml copy it to the location where your exe is present

Comment: This is if you want to show XML directly in DataGrid, however if you want to parse it in codebehind and do operations on it then I would say you use Linq queries to parse XML and create your model objects like Mode/Beam/etc and bind those objects for presentation

Comment: I really appreciate your help Joshi sir,
the thing is i am not able to execute the code what you have given...
it is Throwing me multiple errors..
So i would really like you to provide the whole xaml code that works fine for me ...